# Table row server side click in repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

I have a repeater which has table as per below code and I need to send param to code behind when table row is clicked.
At the moment I am passing it on LinkButton1 click.
I have also tried wrapping  in LinkButton but it's not working
How do I do this?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" OnItemCreated="Repeater1_ItemCreated">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dttable dataTable no-footer" style="border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(252, 253, 250); text-align: center; font-weight: 700; width: 100%;" id="JsDataTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="JsDataTable_info">
            <thead style="width: 100%">
                <tr style="color: #fff; width: 100%;">
                    <td id="tdSr">Sr</td>
                    <td id="tdCode" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnCode" runat="server" CommandName="CourseNo" CssClass="linkHeader">Code<i class = "fa fa-fw fa-sort" ></i></asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                    <td id="tdName" style="width: 50%; white-space: nowrap; text-align: left;">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnName" runat="server" CommandName="VName" CssClass="linkHeader">Name<i class = "fa fa-fw fa-sort" ></i></asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                    <td id="tdType" style="width: 20%">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnType" runat="server" CommandName="VType" CssClass="linkHeader">Type<i class = "fa fa-fw fa-sort" ></i></asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="width: 100%">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr id="trID" runat="server" class="box" style="height: 30px; color: #08516F; vertical-align: middle;">
            <td style="color: #004457; border-right: 1px solid #004457; vertical-align: middle;" class="labelTxt">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfAllowSubscription" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("AllowSubscription") %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="lblSR" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="color: #004457; border-right: 1px solid #004457; vertical-align: middle;">
                <%#Eval("CourseNo") %>
            </td>
            <td style="color: #004457; border-right: 1px solid #004457; text-align: left !important; vertical-align: middle;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="PlayPrev" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' CssClass="name"></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>

            <td style="color: #004457; border-right: 1px solid #004457; vertical-align: middle;">
                <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("VType") %>' runat="server" ID="lblType" CssClass="lblType" Style="font-family: 'Segoe UI semiBold' !important;"></asp:Label>
                <span id="lblsubtype" runat="server" class="subtype_color T"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody>
              </table>  
               <div id="repeatorEmptyRow" runat="server" style="text-align: center; color: red;">
                  No matching records found
               </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: hello, give backend side code. C# or vb

Comment: all repeater events code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want the value of the `CommandArgument` in `Repeater1_ItemCommand`. But if you try to cast the sender to a LinkButton that will not work because the Sender is the Repeater, not the button inside.

So cast the CommandSource and get the correct value.

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = e.CommandSource as LinkButton;
    Label1.Text = lb.CommandArgument;
}
```

You cannot bind a `tr` click directly, so you have to use a trick. You can use jQUery to set the click of the LinkButton to the row itself.

```
<table border="1" id="Repeater1Table">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>Click here</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="PlayPrev" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' CssClass="name"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Repeater1Table tr").each(function () {
            var href = $(this).find(".name").prop("href").split(":")[1];
            $(this).attr("onclick", href); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am doing the same but I want command argument when a table row is clicked and not a particular column. If you check out markup in question, it has table row which is being iterated , I want command to be executed when a <tr> is clicked.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks.... I never thought we can wire up link to row like that... You are the boss man